serilog multi-process sharing not working --- .NET CORE APIs not able to write to the same error file
I have two .NET 8 CORE APIS  ( API-1 & API-2), and I am trying to get them to log any error to the same file to no avail. Only one API is writting to the error file
Test 1

Restart IIS
Genereate error from API-1 -> message is written to error log
Generate error from API-2 -> no message is being written to error log
Generate error from API-1 -> message is written to error log.

Test 2

Restart IIS
Genereate error from API-2 -> message is written to error log
Generate error from API-1 -> no message is being written to error log
Generate error from API-2 -> message is written to error log.

appsettings.json .


"Serilog": {
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Information",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
  "WriteTo": [
    { "Name": "Console" },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "E:/Logs/SerilogAPITester1-.txt",
        "rollingInterval": "Day",
        "fileSizeLimitBytes": 50000000,
        "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
        "shared": true //so other apps can write here too
        //"outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level}]) {Message} {NewLine} {Exception}"
      }
    },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "E:/Logs/Errors-.txt",
        "rollingInterval": "Day",
        "fileSizeLimitBytes": 50000000,
        "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
        "shared": true, //so other apps can write here too
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error"
        //"outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level}]) {Message} {NewLine} {Exception}"
      }
    }
  ]
  //"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithThreadId" ],
  //"Properties": {
  //  "Application": "Tester1",
  //  "Environment": "Prod"
  //}
},



NOTE: The above configuration is for API-1, API-2 will have two changes:


"AppName": "Tester1" --> "Tester2"
"path": "E:/Logs/SerilogAPITester1-.txt" --> "E:/Logs/SerilogAPITester2-.txt"



program.cs


Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration).CreateLogger();



If you can see where I went wrong, please shout! Thanks

original github issue: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-file/issues/315 (note: issue is closed; any answers/suggestions should be posted here for visibility)

:o First time I hear: Two app with same log file. #1 You are complicating your architecture. Two different apps means two different contexts (source code, log, etc) in a distributed infrastructure. #2 If you want to merge the logs, you need a monolith. #3 Anyway.  On linux (netcore) maybe it could works. With windows, good luck

You mentioned you would like to write to the same file, then why did you use 2 different paths fo API and API2?

i want to use TWO different log files for the application logging (detailed logging), and a single LOG file for the errors. This helps identifying any errors by monitoring a single file

Steps to debug:

Even though you have used "shared": true, there might still be issues with file locking when two different processes try to write to the same file simultaneously.

Try adding : Buffered: false
Note: It might affect performance in some cases - https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/650



Verify that the log paths are exactly the same in both API configurations for the shared error log.

From your case - the file paths are different "E:/Logs/SerilogAPITester1-.txt" and "E:/Logs/SerilogAPITester2-.txt"



Best approach - Consider setting up a centralized logging service or use a different sink like Serilog.Sinks.Seq or Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch for handling logs from multiple sources.
Configuration Template for your reference:
{
  "Serilog": {
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
        "System": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console", "Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      { "Name": "Console" },
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "E:/Logs/SharedErrors-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": 50000000,
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true,
          "shared": true,
          "buffered": false,  // Add this line
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

Debugging tips:

If the issue persists, enable verbose logging for Serilog to
troubleshoot further.
Monitor the logs for any messages related to
file access issues or configuration problems.


Sorry, i missed your answer. I will try this and let you know how it goes. It might take me a while but will def do it
