Three ASP.NET Core Web API not able to share and write to the same file sink using Serilog
I have three ASP.NET Core Web APIs hosted in IIS on the same machine which use different configuration file to setup Serilog but all of them point to the same log file.
Here is an example of my configuration:
{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.File"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
      "Default": "Verbose",
      "Override": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "Warning"
      }
    },
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "D:/Logs/Log-.txt",
          "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
          "rollingInterval": "Day",
          "rollOnFileSizeLimit": "true",
          "fileSizeLimitBytes": "1000000",
          "retainedFileCountLimit": 90,
          "shared": "true",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level:u3}] [{App}{ThreadId}] {SourceContext} [{Caller}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithThreadId" ]
  }
}

But only one of the three APIs is able to write to the D:/Logs/Log-.txt.
I tried and changed the output path of each API to separate files, and it works.
But my question is even with shared: true why three different Web APIs are not able to write to the same file.
Note: I created three different services - two windows services and one WPF application and they all were able to share and write to one single log file, so it seems this limitation is only limited to ASP.NET Core Web APIs.
Note2: I check on local, all three WebAPIs are able to write to a single file in debug mode, but not when hosted in IIS. Could IIS have a role into why this seems to be an issue?

Found a similar question with one answer that suggests to try out certain solutions but none of them worked for me -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78768537/serilog-multi-process-sharing-not-working-net-core-apis-not-able-to-write-t

See if this question has the answer you're looking for.
